# Node app is not running on my PC but running fine with other PC of my team (using Git)

Tags: node.js, git, npm, travis-ci

Our team makes a project with a Node.js server and use GitHub as source control. The problem is when I will run the server. I use next steps to test if the master will start the application.

```
git checkout master
git pull
npm update
node .\backend\server.js
```

The last comment gives me next error.

```
D:\***\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:82
  if (!options.clientID) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option'); }
                           ^

TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy (D:\Documenten\WatchFriends\Web\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:82:34)
    at new Strategy (D:\Documenten\WatchFriends\Web\node_modules\passport-google-oauth20\lib\strategy.js:52:18)
    at module.exports.config (D:\Documenten\WatchFriends\Web\backend\data\passport.js:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Documenten\WatchFriends\Web\backend\server.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Other team partners are also working on the same repository has done the same steps to test if the master will run. The wierd problem is that they haven't any problem. Also the configuration files that are ignore by the `.gitignore` file are equal.

**Question:** What is the problem why the code doesn't run on my computer and but will run on other computers?

**I've tried to** delete and reclone the project from GitHub, reinstall the node modules and added the ignored files. But it doesn't solve the error. I'm woking with node version 6.9.3 and git version 2.10.2.windows.1.

**Update:**

- Here is the link to our GitHub project: [github.com/WatchFriends/Web](https://github.com/WatchFriends/Web)
- This is the build status of Travis [image: Build Status] *(Just ckecking some gulp tasks but also `npm run build`)*
- Here is the link to Travis: [travis-ci.org/WatchFriends/Web](https://travis-ci.org/WatchFriends/Web)
- Configuration of Travis: [`./.travis.yml` on GitHub](https://github.com/WatchFriends/Web/blob/master/.travis.yml)

  ```
  install:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g angular-cli
  language: node_js
  script:
    - gulp html
    - gulp scss
    - gulp ts
    - gulp node
  node_js:
    - "6.9"
  cache:
    directories:
      - node_modules
      - bower_components
  ```

Comment: You should compare environment variables on your PC and your team members PCs

Comment: It's obviously missing something, maybe there's a config folder or file where you have to set something first? What's happening in strategy.js at line 82?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is why you should use continuous integration systems like Travis, Circle or Codeship to run your tests on a clean system - to avoid the situation that the application doesn't work but someone says "it works on my system".

Clearly your system has to be different in some way from the systems that the code works on. You can have different software installed, different services running, different libraries, different environment variables, a different OS or maybe you're doing something different during the installation or starting of the application.

Start using CI and you'll immediately see what's wrong.

Also use npm to start your service:

```
npm start
```

so that you know that you are running the same command as everyone else.

Comment: Sorry but we use Travis. [this is our status](https://travis-ci.org/WatchFriends/Web.svg?branch=master) and [here is our project](https://github.com/WatchFriends/Web)